# error while loading image into Java Database

Tags: java, image, web

why do I get this error when trying to load an image into a java database?

This is the code:

```
        boolean estado = false;

            ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                FileItemFactory file = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(file);
                List items = fileUpload.parseRequest((RequestContext) request);
                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                    FileItem fileItems = (FileItem) items.get(i);

                    if (!fileItems.isFormField()) {
                        File f = new File("C:\\images\\" + fileItems.getName());
                        fileItems.write(f);
                        dtoFotos.setRuta(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else {
                        lista.add(fileItems.getString());
                    }
                }

                estado = daoFotos.insertarFoto(dtoFotos);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                request.setAttribute("message", e);
            }
```

I got this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade cannot be cast to
> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.RequestContext

how can I solve this?

Comment: The error tells you that you cannot  cast to `RequestContext`, like you're doing here `fileUpload.parseRequest((RequestContext) request);`

Comment: Why *are* you casting btw?

Comment: Try to replace `request` with `request.getServletContext()` before you cast

Comment: The method takes type `HttpServletRequest`

Comment: no bro, I get the same error. I tried to save the image directly in the database but it doesn't work either.

Comment: What type is your `request`?

Comment: I send it from a jsp as a POST and receive the parameter as a String to send it to the database as a varchar.

Comment: I don't know if that was meant to be an answer to my question. But my question would be answered by telling me the value of `System.out.println(request.getClass())`

Answer (score 0):

1. According to the [`ServletFileUpload` javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html#parseRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-) there's no need to cast the `request` to `RequestContext`, because `request` of [`RequestFacade`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/RequestFacade.html) implements `HttpServletRequest`
2. Also, there's no need to cast file item to `FileItem`, instead the type should be specified and `for-each` loop should be used:

```java
List<FileItem> items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
for (FileItem fileItems : items) {
    if (!fileItems.isFormField()) {
        File f = new File("C:\\images\\" + fileItems.getName());
        fileItems.write(f);
        dtoFotos.setRuta(f.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        lista.add(fileItems.getString());
    }
}
```